# Print all values greater than some value without using booleans in R?

Tags: r

anyone got any idea how to print element greater than some value from a set without using booleans?

E.g., suppose I have the set x, which includes the elements (1, 4, 6, 3, 5, 2, 9).
Obviously, we can print all the values of x greater than 5 using the following code:
x[x>5]
But this way of coding uses booleans (it uses TRUE, FALSE etc.)

But is there any way to do this using solely integers?
I was thinking about some sort of loop that would start contain the number of elements, and then do
x[c(variable)]

but I don't know really.
Please help?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without a logical vector?

Comment: Its part of some programme Im trying to teach students, and I actually started wondering whether this is even possible

Comment: Are you looking for `which(x > 5)`?

Comment: I am curious how you would want to represent the fact that something is true or false (in your case equal or greater than equal) without the usage of booleans